# What "MOV AX, [BX]" actually does?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers, emu8086, masm32

I am using x86 MASM32 Assembler. When code started, address of BX always does 078BH. What is the reaseon of this situation? Otherwise, There is a question like "Write assembly code which generates 8B07H machine code". I guess that this question solves like that "MOV AX, [BX]" but [BX] is 078BH, is not 8B07H.

Comment: Is this the actual question you are being asked: https://media.cheggcdn.com/media/39e/39e49725-b2e6-4c64-9edd-eaa5c738a8c2/image.png ?

Comment: `BX` is a register. Registers do not have addresses: they have names (e.g. BX), and they hold values/contents (e.g. `BX` holds a 16-bit value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather confusing, so I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

> What `MOV AX, [BX]` actually does?

The instruction ...

- ... adds the value of the `BX` register to the base address of the segment specified by the `DS` register
  It depends on the operating mode of the CPU ("real mode" or "protected mode") how the base address is calculated from the `DS` register.
- ... reads one byte from the memory at the address represented by that sum
- ... writes that byte to the low byte of `AX` (this means: `AL`)
- ... reads the next byte from the memory
- ... writes that byte to the high byte of `AX` (this means: `AH`)

Let's say that `BX` contains the value `456h` and the segment specified by `DS` has the base address `23000h`. Then the address is `23000h+456h` = `23456h`. Let's say the memory at address `23456h` contains the value `0CDh` and the memory at address `23457h` contains the value `0ABh`, then `AX` will contain the value `0ABCDh` after the operation.

> When code started, address of BX always does 078BH. What is the reason of this situation?

I don't know about emu8086.

On a real computer, the values of the registers depend on the operating system of the computer. Under my Ubuntu Linux version, `BX` has the value 0 when the program starts.

> Otherwise, There is a question like "Write assembly code which generates `8B07H` machine code". I guess that this question solves like that `MOV AX, [BX]` but `[BX]` is `078BH`, is not `8B07H`.

`8B07H` is a 16-bit number, but the memory of x86 systems is organized in bytes (8-bit units). So the first question is: What does `8B07H` mean in this case?

It might mean that the first byte shall be `08Bh` and the second byte shall be `07h`.

In this case the instruction `MOV [AX], BX` would do the job, not `MOV AX, [BX]`:

This instruction does more or less the opposite of `MOV AX, [BX]`: It writes data to memory. This time, the data in the register `BX` is written to the memory specified by the registers `DS` and `AX`.

Because on x86 systems the low byte of some data is stored in the first byte and the high byte is stored in the second byte, the value `1234h` would be stored as two bytes:`34h` in the first byte and `12h` in the second one.

The same is true for `78Bh`: `8Bh` is stored in the first byte and `07h` is stored in the second one.

**EDIT**

> The question is "Write a assembly code which generates 8B07H value.".
> ...
> I searched this question on The Internet and solving is `MOV AX, [BX]`.

In RAM memory, you can only store numbers. To store the letter "A", the number 65 is stored (as an example).

Assembler instructions are also stored as numbers.

The instruction `MOV AX, [BX]` is stored as the two numbers `8Bh` and `07h`. However, ...

> So, after assembly program executed, finally 8B07H value should be generated in a register(AX, BX etc.).

... this has nothing to do with what the program is doing:

The instruction **is** stored as `8Bh` and `07h`, just like the word `main` in a Java program **is** stored as the letters `m`, `a`, `i` and `n`.

This means that the memory already contains the values `8Bh` and `07h` **before** the program is started.

> What is the reason of this situation?

Every inventor of a new CPU type has to define the meanings of the numbers. For ARM CPUs (this is what the new Apple PCs or the Raspberry Pi use) in 16-bit mode, `8Bh` and `07h` means `lsls r3, r1, #30` which is a completely different operation than `mov ax, [bx]`.

You have to look into the documentation for the corresponding CPU to know what exactly `8Bh` and `07h` means.

In the Intel 8086 documentation, you'll find a table that contains the following line (on page 4-31):

```
1st byte |2nd byte   |more bytes|meaning
---------+-----------+----------+---------------
   ...   |     ...   |   ...    |  ...
   8B    |mod reg r/m|  disp    | MOV reg16, r/m
   ...   |     ...   |   ...    |  ...
```

The value `07h` is `00 000 111` (binary). This is the second byte (`mod reg r/m`) so you look up some other tables (in the 8086 documentation, these tables are on page 4-20):

The combination of `mod=00` and `r/m=111` means: `r/m` = `[BX]`
`reg=000` means: `reg16` = `AX`

So the instruction `8Bh`, `07h` is `MOV AX, [BX]`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I guess i could not explain my question correctly. There is a question from my college exam.The question is "Write a assembly code which generates 8B07H value.". So, after assembly program executed, finally 8B07H value should be generated in a register(AX, BX etc.). I searched this question on The Internet and solving is MOV AX, [BX]. To conclude,when i looked register values in emu8086,I always see that address of BX([BX]) is 078BH at the begining of the program.So why first address of the program is 078BH?Why the question that I asked is solving like this.

Comment: `mov [ax], bx` is not encodeable because there is no `ax` Effective Address encoding.

Comment: @nick Please see my "edit" section.